# How to move files into folders where folder name is the date created?

Tags: node.js, file, date, node-modules

I have a lot of files that I want to move into folders where the folder format is YYYY-MM and any file that was created within that YYYY-MM should be placed inside it. I would like to do this using `nodejs`

**Questions**

1. How can I get a file's date created and use it to move into folders based on YYYY-MM format?
2. How would I be able to group the files by YYYY-MM from the created date of the file?

**files**

1. file1 --> created=2023-01-01
2. file2 --> created=2023-01-05
3. file3 --> created=2023-01-20
4. file4 --> created=2023-05-06
5. file5 --> created=2023-06-04
6. file6 --> created=2023-06-05
7. file7 --> created=2023-05-25

**Expected outcome**

1. Folder:2023-01 -- file1,file2, file3
2. folder:2023-05 -- file4, file7
3. folder:2023-06 -- file5, file6

**what i tried and where i am stuck**

```
const fs = require('fs');

const folderName = '/Users/myuser/targetFolder';

try {
  if (!fs.existsSync(folderName)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(folderName);
    /***** stuck here as I can't figure out how to access the file create ****/
    fs.readdirSync(folderPath).map(fileName => {
      return path.join(folderPath, fileName);
    });

  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now get stats for each file, extract date created from it, construct year folder name from the date, create the year folder, and move the file to the folder.

Try this (note you may need to modify input/target folders,
as this works with the following input folder and output folder structure):

```
├───input
│       file1
│       file2
│
└───targetFolder
    ├───YYYY-MM
    │       file1
    │
    └───YYYY-MM
            file2
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
    
const inputFilesFolder = 'input';

const targetFolder = 'targetFolder';
    
try {

    if (!fs.existsSync(targetFolder)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(targetFolder);
    }

    fs.readdirSync(inputFilesFolder).map(fileName => {


        // get file metadata
        const stats = fs.statSync(`${inputFilesFolder}/${fileName}`);

        console.log(fileName, ' stats: ', stats);

        // skip directory
        if (!stats.isDirectory()) {

            // get date created
            const birthtime = stats.birthtime;

            // construct year folder name
            const year = String(birthtime.getFullYear());

            const month = String(birthtime.getMonth() + 1);

            // pad month..
            const monthPadded = month.length == 1 ? '0' + month : month;

            const yearFolderName = `${year}-${monthPadded}`;

            console.log('year folder name', yearFolderName);

            // create year folder name if not exists
            if (!fs.existsSync(`${targetFolder}/${yearFolderName}`)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(`${targetFolder}/${yearFolderName}`);
            }

            // move file
            try {
                fs.renameSync(`${inputFilesFolder}/${fileName}`, `${targetFolder}/${yearFolderName}/${fileName}`)
                console.log('moved', fileName);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }        
        }

    });

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```